# How can I split my koa routes into separate files? Middleware problem

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

Am trying to split koa routes into separate files.
I'm having folder structure like this for routes.

```
routes/
   __index.js
   auth.js
   user.js
```

So if trying with method one means it's working perfectly. But going with dynamic way that is method 2 means it's not working properly. All routes getting hitting, that's not the problem, but at the same time for **auth** route also it's going inside **middleware.isAuthorized**.

**Method 1**

```
const routesToEnable = {
    authRoute: require('./auth'),
    userRoute: require('./user')
};

for (const routerKey in routesToEnable) {
    if (routesToEnable[routerKey]) {
        const nestedRouter = routesToEnable[routerKey];
        if (routerKey == 'authRoute') {
            router.use(nestedRouter.routes(), nestedRouter.allowedMethods());
        } else {
            router.use(middleware.isAuthorized, nestedRouter.routes(), nestedRouter.allowedMethods());
        }
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

**Method 2**

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => (file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== '__index.js' && file.slice(-3) === ".js"))
    .forEach(file => {
        // console.info(`Loading file ${file}`);
        const routesFile = require(`${__dirname}/${file}`);
        switch (file) {
            case 'auth.js':
                router.use(routesFile.routes(), routesFile.allowedMethods());
                break;
            default:
                router.use(middleware.isAuthorized, routesFile.routes(), routesFile.allowedMethods());
                break;
        }
    });

module.exports = router;
```

How can i use method two without middleware for auth route itself. Can anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved as by own. Previously i used to combine routes with middleware also in the same line.

```
router.use(middleware.isAuthorized, routesFile.routes(), routesFile.allowedMethods());
```

But that's the wrong way I used to define route. **router.use()** uses the middleware to all the routes. So now i just splitted my routes into separate router use with individual path. Mentioned in the document [Koa router](https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/HEAD/API.md#routerusepath-middleware--router)

Solved answer

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== '__index.js' && file.slice(-3) === ".js"))
  .forEach(file => {
    const routesFile = require(`${__dirname}/${file}`);
    if (file !== 'auth.js') {
      routesFile.stack.forEach(elem => { router.use(elem.path, middleware.isAuthorized); });
    }
    router.use(routesFile.routes(), routesFile.allowedMethods());
  });
```